# Why is the integral of $dx$ equal to $x$?

Tags: integration, differential

Please give a thorough explanation, not just "$dx$ is the derivative of $x$, so the antiderivative of $dx$ is $x$, duh".

Comment: and by integral i mean the definite integral

Comment: Try calculating the area of a rectangle with height=1 ( since $dx$=$1dx$, based on the Real line going from $a$ to $b$

Comment: The derivative of $x$ isn't "dx", it's $1$.  So $x$ is an antiderivative of $1$.

Comment: @DBF, Just saw your comment, Sorry for repeating your answer.

Comment: random follow up question...i have the equation force = mass*(dv(t)/dt), where v is velocity and t is time. the book says to multiply both sides by dt to get f(dt) = m(dv), then integrate the left equation from a=t(initial) b=t(final) and integrate the right equation from a=v(initial) to b=v(final). can you explain why these operations are legal?

Comment: If it's the definite integral, you need to give bounds.

Comment: @Arash: No problem, I've done unknowingly a few times myself.

Comment: Regarding the follow up question, calculations like this that involve "multiplying both sides by $dt$" can usually be rephrased in a way where you work only with $\frac{dv}{dt}$.  In this case, we have $f(t) = m v'(t)$, so $\int_a^b f(t) \,dt = \int_a^b m v'(t) \, dt = m v(t) |_a^b = m v(b) - m v(a) = m( v_f - v_i)$.

Answer (score 16):

It's not. It's equal to x+C.

More seriously, You're not integrating "dx". When we write $\int dx$,we mean to solve the problem $\int 1dx$. "dx" has no meaning outside "I'm trying to integrate by x" or "I'm taking the x derivative", unless you possibly mean $x\cdot d$.

Comment: random follow up question...i have the equation force = mass*(dv(t)/dt), where v is velocity and t is time.  the book says to multiply both sides by dt to get f(dt) = m(dv), then integrate the left equation from a=t(initial) b=t(final) and integrate the right equation from a=v(initial) to b=v(final).

can you explain why these operations are legal?

Comment: @nuhrin: This should hopefully explain things: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47092/physicists-not-mathematicians-can-multiply-both-sides-with-dx-why

Comment: Of course, "you're integrating 'dx'" *can* be made to make sense, and it's a really useful notion, even at the introductory level. Unfortunately, AFAIK it's usually only explicitly discussed in differential or algebraic geometry. However, the ideas are still usually used often in calculus and physics, giving the student a chance to learn it through osmosis.

Answer (score 3):

IMO, a better viewpoint on the problem is:

> Okay, definite integrals are designed so that $\int_P \, df = f(b) - f(a)$, where $a,b$ are the endpoints of the path $P$ (think of a path as being a line segment). Why can we compute this as a limit of Riemann sums?

The answer is analysis -- we take the problem and break it into smaller pieces that are hopefully easier to solve. In this case, we split the path $P$ into a sequence of many smaller paths (e.g. split $[0,5]$ into $[0,1]$ then $[1,2]$ then $[2,3]$ then $[3,4]$ then $[4,5]$).

If $f$ is a continuously differentiable function, then differential approximation tells us that over a small interval $[x, x+\epsilon]$, the definite integral of $df$ -- that is, the value $f(x+\epsilon) - f(x)$ -- is approximately $f'(x) \epsilon$ (we could replace $x$ with any point in $[x, x+\epsilon]$ if we like).

If we add this up over all the small paths, the result is a Riemann sum, and if we take a suitable limit, the approximation error goes to zero.

For $f(x) = x$ specifically, we're adding up $\epsilon$ for each of the paths: no matter how we split $[a,b]$ into paths, the resulting sum is going to be $b-a$.

---

As usual, non-standard analysis gives us a cleaner description: we split the path $P$ into a hyperfinite number of paths $P_n$, each one of infinitesimal length. Adding up $f'(x) \epsilon$ for each one gives us a value infintiesimally close to the value of the integral.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the integral $\int_0^xdt$ is the area of a rectangle by length of $x$ and width of 1.

Comment: random follow up question...i have the equation force = mass*(dv(t)/dt), where v is velocity and t is time. the book says to multiply both sides by dt to get f(dt) = m(dv), then integrate the left equation from a=t(initial) b=t(final) and integrate the right equation from a=v(initial) to b=v(final). can you explain why these operations are legal?

Comment: It does not makes sense to have the bound variable in the limits.

Comment: @L.F., it was just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

To take a definite integral from $a$ to $b$ of $dx$ is to take the infinitesimal quantity $dx$ and sum the infinite number of occurrences of it between $a$ and $b$. $dx$ is defined so that the sum from $a$ to $a+1$ of $dx$ is always 1. Or, if you view $dx$ as the mesh of a partition, as in the Riemann integral's definition, then you're approximating a set of quantities whose sum is by definition the length of the interval of integration.

Comment: One has a very precise definition of what an integral is, why would you want to change it into "...is to take the infinitesimal quantity..."?

Comment: random follow up question...i have the equation force = mass*(dv(t)/dt), where v is velocity and t is time. the book says to multiply both sides by dt to get f(dt) = m(dv), then integrate the left equation from a=t(initial) b=t(final) and integrate the right equation from a=v(initial) to b=v(final). can you explain why these operations are legal?

Comment: @nuhrin This follows from the chain rule. On definite integrals, the change of variables requires a change of bounds of integration, but $v$ being a function of $t$ in the first place, the appropriate bounds are the values of $v$ at the initial and final time; abbreviated to just the initial and final $v$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Because then you can perform formal integrals, say with Kähler differentials or cohomology. Besides, it's what the limit definition says anyway, just through a different model. I don't see how infinitesimals are imprecise in the slightest.

Comment: @LokiClock I know you can make infinitesimals precise, but then you'd have to explain to the OP how that is done (else you still have to stick to "summing infinitely many yadda yadda" which is still imprecise and informal), and I don't think that is really sensible. We have good elementary **and** intuitive definitions of what a Riemann integral is, which seems what you're talking about. I also think it is quite ridiculous to bring up differential forms into the picture here.

Comment: @LokiClock: Infinitesimals are physicists' and engineers' domain — nothing to do with differential forms, Kähler differentials, or cohomology. The math is made rigorous by model theory and non-standard analysis. Still nothing to do with what you cite.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff It's how I think of them, that's all. I consider that an elementary and intuitive definition of a Riemann integral, because infinitesimals are an elementary and intuitive concept for me.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sure it has to do with those things. The dual space to the tangent space is the cotangent space. Viewing the cotangent space as the cochains and the tangent space as the chains, you can formally integrate a cochain - a formal infinitesimal - over a set of chains by summing over the values of the evaluation map as the chain varies.

Answer (score 0):

From $0$ t0 $x > 0$ and $N = 1,2,3,\ldots$:
$$
\overbrace{\quad%
{x \over N}\times 1\quad +\quad {x \over N}\times 1
\quad + \quad
\cdots\quad
+\quad
{x \over N}\times 1\quad}^{N\,\,\,\,\, \mbox{times}}
=
N\times{x \over N}
=
\color{#ff0000}{\large x}
$$